# How can I make vim only write to file after buffer has been modified?

Tags: zsh, vim, vimrc

I have this function which sources my .zshrc only if it has been modified in vim but I recently reinstalled Windows and WSL and then used my old .zshrc and .vimrc to get my setup back but this specific function doesn't work like it did before:

```bsh
function zshrc () {
    local original_ctime="$(zstat +ctime -- ~/.zshrc)" 2>/dev/null
    vim ~/.zshrc || return
    [[ -n $original_ctime ]] || return
    if [[ $original_ctime != "$(zstat +ctime -- ~/.zshrc 2>/dev/null)" ]]
    then
        source ~/.zshrc
    fi
}
```

This function is supposed to check if the file creation time has changed. [See here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/587493/how-can-i-perform-a-bash-zsh-command-subsequent-to-saving-a-file-in-vim).

Before I reinstalled WSL I could run `zshrc` and save the vim buffer using `:wq` (without making any changes) and then vim would not overwrite the original file so it WON'T `source ~/.zshrc` and if I DO make changes then only vim will overwrite the original file, so the function WILL `source  ~/.zshrc`. I'm assuming some defaults were maybe changed in vim so how can I get that specific behaviour back?

I understand that I can just exit vim with `:q!` to get this but when I'm editing different files quickly then I'll use `:wq` without thinking about it and then it sources .zshrc again without any changes.

Comment: That's strange: I'd expect `:wq` to always save the file. If it didn't, I'd consider it a bug. Are you sure this wasn't a bug in WSL?

Comment: fyi, ctime is not creation time, it's inode change status time. It's probably mtime you want here (for the age of the "contents" of the file). See also the -H/-A options of `stat` to avoid the fork.

Comment: Another option is to compare a checksum before and after.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' At least that's what I thought was happening 'cause I always exit with `:wq` and if I didn't modify the buffer then `zstat +ctime` would return the same time as before so I assumed vim didn't write the buffer to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get in the habit of doing `Z` `Z`
(i.e., <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>). 
If the buffer has been modified, this will do `:wq`. 
If the buffer hasn't been modified, it will simply exit without saving.

Comment: Also `:x` instead of `:wq`.